# How to tell programmatically if a remote Bluetooth device is using E0 encryption?

Tags: android, kotlin, encryption, bluetooth

I am writing scanning app in Android, using Kotlin. I want to gather data about security measures, like E0 stream cipher, ECDH with P-192 curve, ECDH with P-256 elliptic curve, AES-CC.

I learned that before Bluetooth 4.2, E0 was a main encryption method. And after this version, AES-CCM was used. But, as far as I know, gathering info about Bluetooth version is even harder, because there is no concrete field that returns that info, you need to kinda figure it out. So I don't know, how useful that is.